# identifying target folder for Outlook365 "Archive" action

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices

The Outlook365 web app has an `E` keyboard shortcut (and an `Archive` menu item).  The first time you use it with a selected message, Outlook lets the user create an "Archive" folder or pick an existing folder for quick message archiving.  After that, pressing the `E` key will automatically move the selected message(s) to the archive folder they'd initially created or selected.

How can an EWS client programmatically determine which folder has been selected as the `E` archive target?